# Postgresql: Performance of query with multiple join conditions

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I have a problem with the performance of a query.
I have article-numbers in one table (~10k entries) and a huge table (~5,000,000 entries) with entries, which belong to the article-numbers. The article-numbers have 10 digits and the entries in the huge table have a prefix structure:

```
0000000000: all articles are referenced
xx00000000: all articles with the first two entries xx are referenced 
etc
```

Here is an example

```
small table:
0123456789: Wine
1234567899: Cheese
```

huge table:

```
0000000000: in stock in all shops
0100000000: best before date in two weeks in shop x
0120000000: few in stock in shop y
```

I need all informations of the huge table for all products as output, so i need to match 0120000000 to all products with the same beginning.

```
select art_numb, information
from small_table
left join huge_table on art_numb = info_numb 
or length(rtrim(info_numb, '0')) between 6 AND 9 AND "left"(info_numb, 9) = "left"(art_numb, 9)
or length(rtrim(info_numb, '0')) between 4 AND 5 AND "left"(info_numb, 5) = "left"(art_numb, 5)
or length(rtrim(info_numb, '0')) =3 AND "left"(info_numb, 3) = "left"(art_numb, 3)
or length(rtrim(info_numb, '0')) between 1 AND 2 AND "left"(info_numb, 2) = "left"(art_numb, 2)
or length(rtrim(info_numb, '0')) = 0
```

This was ridiculous slow.
The fastest Statement (until now) was made of 6 union-blocks:

```
select small.prod_code,
    additional_infos.information,
    additional_infos.meaning
from small
left join huge on small.prod_code = huge.code
left join additional_infos on additional_infos.information = huge.information
union all
select small.prod_code,
    additional_infos.information,
    additional_infos.meaning
from small
left join huge on length(rtrim(huge.code, '0')) between 6 AND 9 AND "left"(huge.code, 9) = "left"(small.prod_code, 9)
left join additional_infos on additional_infos.information = huge.information
union all
select small.prod_code,
    additional_infos.information,
    additional_infos.meaning
from small
left join huge on length(rtrim(huge.code, '0')) between 4 AND 5 AND "left"(huge.code, 5) = "left"(small.prod_code, 5)
left join additional_infos on additional_infos.information = huge.information
union all
select small.prod_code,
    additional_infos.information,
    additional_infos.meaning
from small
left join huge on length(rtrim(huge.code, '0')) =3 AND "left"(huge.code, 3) = "left"(small.prod_code, 3)
left join additional_infos on additional_infos.information = huge.information
union all
select small.prod_code,
    additional_infos.information,
    additional_infos.meaning
from small
left join huge on length(rtrim(huge.code, '0')) between 1 AND 2 AND "left"(huge.code, 2) = "left"(small.prod_code, 2)
left join additional_infos on additional_infos.information = huge.information
union all
select small.prod_code,
    additional_infos.information,
    additional_infos.meaning
from small
left join huge on length(rtrim(huge.code, '0')) = 0
left join additional_infos on additional_infos.information = huge.information;
```

Is there a possibility to speed up my query?

The queries gave the right output but they are slow, i would like to have a faster statement

huge table:

```
0100000000  info a
0100100000  info b
0100100000  info c
0100100000  info d
0100200000  info e
0100200000  info c
0100200000  info d
0100300000  info c
0100300000  info d
0100300000  info f
0100400000  info b
0100400000  info d
0105100000  info c
0105100110  info g
0105100110  info h
0105100440  info d
0105100440  info e
0105151630  info i
0105151630  info k
```

small table

```
0100100003  q
0100100004  w
0100100008  e
0100200003  r
0100200005  t
0100200009  y
0100300003  n
0100300004  i
0100300008  o
0100400001  p
0100400002  a
0105100112  s
0105100111  d
0105100444  f
0105100445  g
0105100446  h
0105151633  j
0105151631  k
0105151632  l
```

```
create table small (
    prod_code text primary key,
    title text);

create table huge (
    code text,
    information text); 

create table additional_infos (
    information text primary key,
    meaning text);

create index index_laenge_code on huge(length(rtrim(code, '0')));

create index index_first2_code on huge(left(code, 2));
create index index_first3_code on huge(left(code, 3));
create index index_first5_code on huge(left(code, 5));
create index index_first9_code on huge(left(code, 9));
```

```
"Append  (cost=24.00..300.84 rows=5280 width=96) (actual time=0.083..0.312 rows=142 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=35"
"  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=24.00..46.30 rows=880 width=96) (actual time=0.082..0.088 rows=19 loops=1)"
"        Output: small.prod_code, additional_infos.information, additional_infos.meaning"
"        Hash Cond: (small.prod_code = huge.code)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=6"
"        ->  Seq Scan on public.small  (cost=0.00..18.80 rows=880 width=32) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=19 loops=1)"
"              Output: small.prod_code, small.title"
"              Buffers: shared hit=1"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=23.75..23.75 rows=20 width=96) (actual time=0.043..0.044 rows=20 loops=1)"
"              Output: huge.code, additional_infos.information, additional_infos.meaning"
"              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"              Buffers: shared hit=2"
"              ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1.45..23.75 rows=20 width=96) (actual time=0.033..0.037 rows=20 loops=1)"
"                    Output: huge.code, additional_infos.information, additional_infos.meaning"
"                    Hash Cond: (additional_infos.information = huge.information)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on public.additional_infos  (cost=0.00..18.80 rows=880 width=64) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=10 loops=1)"
"                          Output: additional_infos.information, additional_infos.meaning"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=1.20..1.20 rows=20 width=64) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=20 loops=1)"
"                          Output: huge.code, huge.information"
"                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on public.huge  (cost=0.00..1.20 rows=20 width=64) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=20 loops=1)"
"                                Output: huge.code, huge.information"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=1"
"  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=9.70..34.04 rows=880 width=96) (actual time=0.062..0.072 rows=27 loops=1)"
"        Output: small_1.prod_code, additional_infos_1.information, additional_infos_1.meaning"
"        Hash Cond: (""left""(small_1.prod_code, 9) = ""left""(huge_1.code, 9))"
"        Buffers: shared hit=8"
"        ->  Seq Scan on public.small small_1  (cost=0.00..18.80 rows=880 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=19 loops=1)"
"              Output: small_1.prod_code, small_1.title"
"              Buffers: shared hit=1"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=9.69..9.69 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=0.051..0.051 rows=6 loops=1)"
"              Output: huge_1.code, additional_infos_1.information, additional_infos_1.meaning"
"              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"              Buffers: shared hit=7"
"              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.15..9.69 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=0.025..0.041 rows=6 loops=1)"
"                    Output: huge_1.code, additional_infos_1.information, additional_infos_1.meaning"
"                    Inner Unique: true"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=7"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on public.huge huge_1  (cost=0.00..1.50 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.006..0.009 rows=6 loops=1)"
"                          Output: huge_1.code, huge_1.information"
"                          Filter: ((length(rtrim(huge_1.code, '0'::text)) >= 6) AND (length(rtrim(huge_1.code, '0'::text)) <= 9))"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 14"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                    ->  Index Scan using additional_infos_pkey on public.additional_infos additional_infos_1  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=6)"
"                          Output: additional_infos_1.information, additional_infos_1.meaning"
"                          Index Cond: (additional_infos_1.information = huge_1.information)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=6"
"  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=9.70..34.04 rows=880 width=96) (actual time=0.037..0.050 rows=39 loops=1)"
"        Output: small_2.prod_code, additional_infos_2.information, additional_infos_2.meaning"
"        Hash Cond: (""left""(small_2.prod_code, 5) = ""left""(huge_2.code, 5))"
"        Buffers: shared hit=14"
"        ->  Seq Scan on public.small small_2  (cost=0.00..18.80 rows=880 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=19 loops=1)"
"              Output: small_2.prod_code, small_2.title"
"              Buffers: shared hit=1"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=9.69..9.69 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=0.027..0.028 rows=12 loops=1)"
"              Output: huge_2.code, additional_infos_2.information, additional_infos_2.meaning"
"              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"              Buffers: shared hit=13"
"              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.15..9.69 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=0.006..0.020 rows=12 loops=1)"
"                    Output: huge_2.code, additional_infos_2.information, additional_infos_2.meaning"
"                    Inner Unique: true"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=13"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on public.huge huge_2  (cost=0.00..1.50 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.002..0.008 rows=12 loops=1)"
"                          Output: huge_2.code, huge_2.information"
"                          Filter: ((length(rtrim(huge_2.code, '0'::text)) >= 4) AND (length(rtrim(huge_2.code, '0'::text)) <= 5))"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 8"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                    ->  Index Scan using additional_infos_pkey on public.additional_infos additional_infos_2  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=12)"
"                          Output: additional_infos_2.information, additional_infos_2.meaning"
"                          Index Cond: (additional_infos_2.information = huge_2.information)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=12"
"  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=9.55..33.89 rows=880 width=96) (actual time=0.043..0.047 rows=19 loops=1)"
"        Output: small_3.prod_code, additional_infos_3.information, additional_infos_3.meaning"
"        Hash Cond: (""left""(small_3.prod_code, 3) = ""left""(huge_3.code, 3))"
"        Buffers: shared hit=2"
"        ->  Seq Scan on public.small small_3  (cost=0.00..18.80 rows=880 width=32) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=19 loops=1)"
"              Output: small_3.prod_code, small_3.title"
"              Buffers: shared hit=1"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=9.54..9.54 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Output: huge_3.code, additional_infos_3.information, additional_infos_3.meaning"
"              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB"
"              Buffers: shared hit=1"
"              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.15..9.54 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                    Output: huge_3.code, additional_infos_3.information, additional_infos_3.meaning"
"                    Inner Unique: true"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on public.huge huge_3  (cost=0.00..1.35 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                          Output: huge_3.code, huge_3.information"
"                          Filter: (length(rtrim(huge_3.code, '0'::text)) = 3)"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 20"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                    ->  Index Scan using additional_infos_pkey on public.additional_infos additional_infos_3  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=64) (never executed)"
"                          Output: additional_infos_3.information, additional_infos_3.meaning"
"                          Index Cond: (additional_infos_3.information = huge_3.information)"
"  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=9.70..34.04 rows=880 width=96) (actual time=0.028..0.035 rows=19 loops=1)"
"        Output: small_4.prod_code, additional_infos_4.information, additional_infos_4.meaning"
"        Hash Cond: (""left""(small_4.prod_code, 2) = ""left""(huge_4.code, 2))"
"        Buffers: shared hit=3"
"        ->  Seq Scan on public.small small_4  (cost=0.00..18.80 rows=880 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=19 loops=1)"
"              Output: small_4.prod_code, small_4.title"
"              Buffers: shared hit=1"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=9.69..9.69 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=0.018..0.019 rows=1 loops=1)"
"              Output: huge_4.code, additional_infos_4.information, additional_infos_4.meaning"
"              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"              Buffers: shared hit=2"
"              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.15..9.69 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=0.007..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                    Output: huge_4.code, additional_infos_4.information, additional_infos_4.meaning"
"                    Inner Unique: true"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on public.huge huge_4  (cost=0.00..1.50 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.002..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                          Output: huge_4.code, huge_4.information"
"                          Filter: ((length(rtrim(huge_4.code, '0'::text)) >= 1) AND (length(rtrim(huge_4.code, '0'::text)) <= 2))"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 19"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                    ->  Index Scan using additional_infos_pkey on public.additional_infos additional_infos_4  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                          Output: additional_infos_4.information, additional_infos_4.meaning"
"                          Index Cond: (additional_infos_4.information = huge_4.information)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=1"
"  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.15..39.34 rows=880 width=96) (actual time=0.008..0.012 rows=19 loops=1)"
"        Output: small_5.prod_code, additional_infos_5.information, additional_infos_5.meaning"
"        Buffers: shared hit=2"
"        ->  Seq Scan on public.small small_5  (cost=0.00..18.80 rows=880 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=19 loops=1)"
"              Output: small_5.prod_code, small_5.title"
"              Buffers: shared hit=1"
"        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.15..9.54 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=19)"
"              Output: additional_infos_5.information, additional_infos_5.meaning"
"              Buffers: shared hit=1"
"              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.15..9.54 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                    Output: additional_infos_5.information, additional_infos_5.meaning"
"                    Inner Unique: true"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on public.huge huge_5  (cost=0.00..1.35 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                          Output: huge_5.code, huge_5.information"
"                          Filter: (length(rtrim(huge_5.code, '0'::text)) = 0)"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 20"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                    ->  Index Scan using additional_infos_pkey on public.additional_infos additional_infos_5  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=64) (never executed)"
"                          Output: additional_infos_5.information, additional_infos_5.meaning"
"                          Index Cond: (additional_infos_5.information = huge_5.information)"
"Planning Time: 1.386 ms"
"Execution Time: 0.534 ms"
```

Comment: Provide a description of the table structure and an example of the data.

Comment: could you please share the DDL for all tables and indexes involved, and the result (in plain text!) from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your query.

Comment: The informations are now in the questions. It just ran on sample data, so of course the query is fast